# Loading lots of point models using libgdx takes a lot of time on Android

Tags: android, model, libgdx

I've developed an Android application to render about 150 point models on the screen using Libgdx game engine. Points coordinates are stored in an SQLite database and after creating a simple sphere model using ModelBuilder, they are transformed according to their location on the scene. The problem is because I need to filter points based on some criteria from the database, I don't have an option to load models on the splash screen, and each time points retrieved from database and models are created. This process takes about 40 seconds which is not efficient for an application. How can optimize this process to decrease loading time?
Below is the snippet to retrieve data from the database and creating point models.

```
List<ModelInstance> modelList = new ArrayList<ModelInstance>();
public void initialize(String sql) {

    pointFeatures = dbSource.fetchPointData(layerName, sql);
    if (pointFeatures.size() > 0) {
        Node node;

        Model m = createPointModel(style);
        for (PointFeature p : pointFeatures) {

            ModelInstance model = new ModelInstance(m);
            node = p.getNode();
            model.transform.setToTranslation(node.getEasting(), node.getHeight(), node.getNorthing());
            modelList.add(model);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void render() {

    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    modelBatch.begin(camera);
    modelBatch.render(modelList);
    modelBatch.end();  

    }
}
```

**Edit 1:**

Using Android Asynctask to fetch data from the database and creating models, result in loading points one by one but related models and textures are rendered as black objects.